# Как создать функцию даты и времени, первым аргументом которой будет число, а вторым единица измерения, которая будет добавлять определенный параметр

Tags: javascript

```
В реализации необходимо использовать объект Date, пример:
```

```js
function add(element, name){   
var myDate = new Date();

if ( name == 'year') {
      myDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullYear() + element);
}
else if ( name == 'month') {
    myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + element);
}
else if ( name == 'day') {
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + element);
}
else if ( name == 'minute') {
    myDate.setMinutes(myDate.getMinutes() + element);
}
else if ( name == 'hour') {
     myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours() + element);
} else {
     console.log("Ne to");
}
 return console.log(myDate);
}

add(2, 'year');
add(6, 'month');
add(3, 'day');
add(23,'hour');
add(6, 'minute');
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть попробовали сами что-то сделать.

Comment: @Igor: уже второй день домашними заданиями бомбят :-\

Comment: @UModeL мне пока еще не удалось израсходовать все ежедневные голоса за закрытие :)

Comment: Игорь, пробую, что не получается вот спрашиваю, прошлое вопрос, вам как пример!

Answer (score 1):

Для такой ситуации лучше использовать enum'ы или константы.
Создать что-то наподобие

```
const TimeUnit= Object.freeze({
    HOUR:   Symbol("hour"),
    MINUTE:  Symbol("minute"),
    SECOND: Symbol("second")
});
```

Далее, создать функцию, которая использует простейший switch-case

```
function addTime(dt, value, timeUnit) {
  switch(timeUnit){
    case TimeUnit.HOUR: // здесь прибавляйте часы
     break;
    case TimeUnit.MINUTE: // здесь прибавляйте минуты
    break;
    case TimeUnit.SECOND: // здесь прибавляйте секунды
    break;
    // И далее по списку делайте что желаете с получаемым объектом.

  }
}
```